# Determine if series are convergent in $(C([0,1]),\| \cdot\|_{\infty})$

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

> Determine whether the following series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ are convergent in the space $(C([0,1]),\|\cdot\|_\infty)$, where
>
> (i) $f_n(t)= \frac{t^n}{n!}$;
>
> (ii) $f_n(t)=\frac{t^n}{2n}$

For (i) I have tried using the Ratio Test to solve... $a_n= \dfrac{t^n}{n!}$ and hence $a_{n+1}= \dfrac{t^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} $

Then $L=\displaystyle \lim_{n\to{\infty}} \bigg| \dfrac{t^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \cdot \dfrac{n!}{t^n} \bigg |$

$L= \displaystyle \lim_{n\to{\infty}} \bigg |\dfrac{t^{n+1}n!}{t^n(n+1)!} \bigg| \ = \bigg|\dfrac{t \cdot n!}{(n+1)!} \bigg| $ $\rightarrow 0 \ as  \ n \rightarrow \infty$

But then how do i use this to show whether it is convergent in the space $(C([0,1]),\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$?

Comment: In (i)  convergence is uniform

Comment: And in (ii), the series does not even converge pointwise at $1$.

Answer (score 1):

$(i)$ The function $t\mapsto f_n(t)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $||f_n||_\infty=\frac{1}{n!}$ so the series $\sum_n ||f_n||_\infty$ is convergent, hence we have the normal convergence of the series $\sum_n f_n(t)$ which implies the uniform convergence and finally we can conclude that the function $t\mapsto \sum_n f_n(t)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.

$(ii)$ we can verify easly by the ratio test that the series $\sum_n f_n(t)$ is pointwise convergent on $[0,1)$, moreover $\lim_{t\to 1}f_n(t)=\frac{1}{2n}=\ell_n$ and the series $\sum_n \ell_n$ is divergent so the series $\sum_n f_n(t)$ is not uniformly convergent on $[0,1)$

Let $0<a<1$. We have 
$$||f_n||_\infty=\frac{a^n}{2n},$$
and the series $\sum_n ||f_n||_\infty$ is convergent so the series $\sum_nf_n(t)$ is uniformly convergent on all compact of $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(t)$$ fails to converge in the second case (plug in $t=1$, and it becomes half the harmonic series).

In the first case, you're dealing with the (MacLaurin) power series for $f(t)=e^t-1,$ which converges everywhere pointwise. You must show that $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\left[\sup_{t\in[0,1]}\left|f(t)-\sum_{n=1}^m f_n(t)\right|\right]=0,$$ or equivalently, that the series is uniformly convergent on $[0,1].$ What do you know about the convergence of power series that could help you with this?